# Android Activity Transition in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, animation, transition

I'm trying to accomplish the following Activity transition in Android:

[image]

In **1** we see an usual ListView. Now (**2**), when I place my finger on a ListView element and slide my finger to the left, all the other ListView elements move away, except the one which has my finger on it. If the transition if completed, the "selected" ListView element expands over the screen and shows some content.

**Question**: Is this transition possible with stock API functions?

Comment: What is inside Element? What's it's expanded height? How are you going to collapse it back?

Comment: i don't know if this is possible, may be you can achieve this by customizing this library https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

Comment: @Leonidos The expansion in (3) is more like an animation. When go back (for example by touching the back arrow), you see the list in (1). In (3) I just need an animation which suggests that the content of the ListView Element you selected is displayed.

Comment: I was working on this but did not have time to continue: Please check https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/AnimationFactory

Comment: Have you tried using a combination of 1) copy the view into a bitmap (or make a secondary instance of it), 2) animate scrollTo on all other children in the listList (or the entire listView with original set to invisible). 3) once that's done, add the copied view to the parent of listView at the global position of where it was in the list. 4) Animate the scale as normal from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @hasanghaforian is techincally correct, subclassing AdapterView is extremely difficult. I suggest you go with this approach. I've included a full working example.

1. Put your ListView view in a relativeLayout
2. OnClick, inflate a copy of your renderer
3. Find the global coordinates for where the renderer sits in relationship to the parent of the ListView
4. Add the copied renderer to the RelativeLayout (parent of ListView)
5. Animate the listView away
6. On the end of that animate, animate your new renderer
7. Profit!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RelativeLayout layout;
    private ListView listView;
    private MyRenderer selectedRenderer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(layout);
        listView = new ListView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.addView(listView, rlp);

        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // find out where the clicked view sits in relationship to the
                // parent container
                int t = view.getTop() + listView.getTop();
                int l = view.getLeft() + listView.getLeft();

                // create a copy of the listview and add it to the parent
                // container
                // at the same location it was in the listview
                selectedRenderer = new MyRenderer(view.getContext());
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(), view
                        .getHeight());
                rlp.topMargin = t;
                rlp.leftMargin = l;
                selectedRenderer.textView.setText(((MyRenderer) view).textView.getText());
                layout.addView(selectedRenderer, rlp);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                // animate out the listView
                Animation outAni = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
                outAni.setDuration(1000);
                outAni.setFillAfter(true);
                outAni.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        ScaleAnimation scaleAni = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 
                                1f, 1f, 2f, 
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        scaleAni.setDuration(400);
                        scaleAni.setFillAfter(true);
                        selectedRenderer.startAnimation(scaleAni);
                    }
                });

                listView.startAnimation(outAni);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return "Hello World " + position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            MyRenderer renderer;
            if (convertView != null)
                renderer = (MyRenderer) convertView;
            else
                renderer = new MyRenderer(MainActivity.this);
            renderer.textView.setText(getItem(position));
            return renderer;
        }
    }

    public class MyRenderer extends RelativeLayout {

        public TextView textView;

        public MyRenderer(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlp.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            textView = new TextView(context);
            addView(textView, rlp);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: just awesome, much less code than I expected.

After testing it, I saw that the animations works great but after the animation if I tap on the screen the list shows up and the copy- render isn't removed from the parent layout.

Also I would like to make it work in distinc orientations (that would be really great :D)

Comment: Its a proof of concept. Implement it to your own needs

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting JellyBean or above, you may use ActivityOptions class to customize the activity launch animation.

Following is pseudo code for achieving this:

```
Intent i = //the intent for the new activity
View v = //the selected list item
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(v, 0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight()).toBundle();
startActivity(i, bundle);
```

Answer (score 3):

A disadvantage of the standard `ListView` is the lack of good physics (and the ability to change it). Therefore, if you want to change it, you simply need to implement your own view.You have to extend a sub class of `ViewGroup` that is [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html),So that AdapterView will be your semi List.

**Details**:

1. Set Adapter for your AdapterView in [`setAdapter(Adapter adapter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setAdapter%28T%29) method.
2. Override [`onLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method to add items to your `AdapterView`.You have to measure and add items as childview in correct position to your list(really your AdapterView).
3. Override [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29),so your list can scroll.And also here you have to do all magics!When user touches an item virtically,list must scroll and when he/she touches horizontally,you have to change position of other items of list and when user picks up his/her finger from screen you have to decide other items be visible or selected item must be extend.

**Sample**:

[Making your own 3D list](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/)(and part 2 of that article) has a good demonstration of what I display for you.It's purpose is creating a 3D list.You can see more details,snippet codes and complete code.Although you have to change it's `onTouchEvent()` to reach what you want.

**Note**:*You can do this even in API1*.

I hope this help you!

Comment: Really interesting.

I will look around to this approach.

Comment: good resource but don't do requestLayout in a AdapterView in the onTouch MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE like that "Making your own 3d List" teaches. This is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, below the ListView, take another linearlayout/relative layout and design it according to your need but make sure that its visibility must be gone. when you tap on the list view item, populate it with your content and do this all on long press. for animation, scale it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

whenevr u press on that list element it should call  animations for this u have to go through the animations.In that animation you should design it and in those animations if u r using imagesmeans go throug 9 patch images